# Cannot install Ubuntu 14.04. Cannot see installation screen when boot from DVD/USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

Hi I have this problem and it is very frustrating. I downloaded 64 bit ubuntu 14.04 and make both DVD and USB drive from the ISO file.

I want to install Ubuntu alongside with my win 8.1. When I choose to boot from USB/DVD under UEFI mode, I can see to options to try or install ubuntu. But if I select one of them, I just see a black screen and it stays that way forever.

SO I can never actually install Ubuntu because I cannot even see the installation screen!

I turned off fast boot in win 8.1 and secure boot in UEFI. I do not know what causes the problem. I built this desktop by my own and the motherboard is Asrock Z77 and CPU is 3570k.

Can anyone help me with this problem? I really need to use ubuntu.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Try reading these [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. Finally I find out the problem is caused by the motherboard. Z77 Extreme 4 has some asmedia SATA and ubuntu does not support Asmedia. So I have to move all the hard drive s and DVD room to Intel SATA then the problem is fixed.